# Prove that $\exists\ C$ such that $T: C \to C$ with $C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I have a problem:

> Let $K$ be a nonempty, closed, bounded and convex subset of reflective Banach space  $X$. Suppose that 
>   $$T:K \to K$$ is *nonexpansive*.
>
> Prove that $\exists\ C$ such that
>   $$T: C \to C$$ 
>   where $C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$ and if $C \ne \left \{ \text{one point} \right \}$ then $C$ is a *diametral set*.
>
> It means that:
>   $\forall x \in C: \ \sup_{y \in C}\left \| x-y \right \|=\text{diam}\ C$.

=====================================

I have trouble when I try to find a solution to the problem.

I'll write here:

- Consider the family $\mathcal{F}$ of all nonempty, closed and convex (thus *weakly compact*) subset of $K$ which are $T$ - invariant, and order this family by set inclusion: For $K_1, \ K_2 \in \mathcal{F},\ K_1 \le K_2$ provided $K_2 \subset K_1$. By Zorn's Lemma, $\mathcal{f}$ has a minimal $C$.
- We'll show that $C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$:

We consider $D=\{z \in C: C \subset \overline{B}(z,r)\} \ne \emptyset$.

Take $z \in D$, because $T$ is *nonexpansive*, we have:
$$T(C) \subset B(Tz,r)$$
Hence, $\overline{\text{conv}}T(C) \subset B(Tz,r)$.

Obviously $\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$ is closed, convex in $K$ then weakly compact. We have 
$$\overline{\text{conv}}T(C) \subset \overline{\text{conv}}C=C$$ then 
$$T(\overline{\text{conv}}T(C))\subset T(C) \subset \overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$$

Therefore, $\overline{\text{conv}}T(C) \in \mathcal{F}$.

Because $\overline{\text{conv}}T(C) \subset C$ and $C$ is minimal then $C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$.

---

How to prove that "if $C \ne \left \{ \text{one point} \right \}$ then $C$ is a *diametral set*"???
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $C = \varnothing$ is allowed, we can always choose $C=\varnothing$. If that is not allowed, look at $X = \mathbb{R}$, $K = [1,\infty)$, and $T(x) = x+1$.

Comment: Thanks **Daniel Fischer**! Yes, if we take $T(x) = x+1$ then $\left \| Tx-Ty \right \|=\left \| x-y \right \|$. Hence, we have $$T: K = [1,\infty) \to [1,\infty)$$ is nonexpansive. And if $C=\emptyset$ then $$\forall x \in C: \ \sup_{y \in C}\left \| x-y \right \|=\text{diam}\ C=0$$. I'm correct since your hint?

Comment: I'm sorry when I have a question If $C \ne \emptyset$ then How to show that...?

Comment: The hint is that in the example $C = \varnothing$ is the only set satisfying the conditions, so if that isn't allowed, as stated, the proposition is false. Is there perhaps an assumption that $K$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, I think so, maybe! And can you show that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I fixed it. But I don't understand $C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$? and why we need $X$ be a reflective Banach space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't understand $C=\overline{\operatorname{conv}}T(C)$?

$\operatorname{conv} A$ is the convex hull of $A$, and $\overline{\operatorname{conv}} A$ denotes the closed convex hull of $A$, that is, $\overline{\operatorname{conv} A}$. So the requirement is that $C$ be equal to the closure of the convex hull of its $T$-image.

> and why we need $X$ be a reflective Banach space?

Because in a reflexive space, every closed convex and bounded subset is weakly compact (compact in the weak topology).

The weak compactness guarantees the existence of a minimal nonempty closed convex $T$-invariant subset, that is, the existence of a nonempty closed convex $C\subset K$ with $T(C)\subset C$ such that no proper nonempty subset of $C$ is closed, convex, and $T$-invariant.

The minimality then guarantees $C = \overline{\operatorname{conv} T(C)}$, since for a nonempty closed convex $T$-invariant $C\subset K$ we have $\overline{\operatorname{conv} T(C)} \subset C$, and since then $T(\overline{\operatorname{conv} T(C)}) \subset T(C) \subset \overline{\operatorname{conv} T(C)}$, the subset $\overline{\operatorname{conv} T(C)}$ of $C$ is also nonempty, closed, convex and $T$-invariant. Minimality says it's $C$.

Such a minimal $C$ either consists of a single fixed point of $T$, or $T$ is fixed-point free on $C$.

In the latter case, $C$ is a diametral set,

$$\sup_{y\in C} \lVert x-y\rVert = \operatorname{diam} C$$

for all $x\in C$ (filling in the details of the proof sketch in Kazimierz Goebel and Brailey Sims, More on minimal invariant sets for nonexpansive mappings):

Suppose there is an $x \in C$ with $\sup\limits_{y\in C} \lVert x-y\rVert = r < \operatorname{diam} C$. Let

$$C_r = \left\{ x\in C : \sup_{y\in C}\lVert x-y\rVert \leqslant r\right\}.$$

Then $C_r \subsetneq C$, since there exist $a,b\in C$ with $\lVert a-b\rVert > r$. $C_r$ is closed, since if $\sup\limits_{y\in C} \lVert x-y\rVert = r+\delta$ with $\delta > 0$, we have $\sup\limits_{y\in C}\lVert z-y\rVert \geqslant r + \delta/2$ for all $z \in C\cap B_{\delta/2}(x)$, and $C_r$ is convex, since for $x_1,x_2\in C_r$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$ we have

$$\lVert (1-\lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2 - y\rVert \leqslant (1-\lambda)\lVert x_1-y\rVert + \lambda \lVert x_2-y\rVert \leqslant (1-\lambda)r+\lambda r = r$$

for all $y\in C$.

Also, $C_r$ is $T$-invariant: Let $x\in C_r$ and $y \in \operatorname{conv} T(C)$. Then there are $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n \in [0,1]$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 1$ and $y_1,\dotsc,y_n\in C$ with $y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i T(y_i)$, and hence

$$\lVert T(x)-y\rVert = \left\lVert T(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i T(y_i)\right\rVert \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert T(x) - T(y_i)\rVert \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert x-y_i\rVert \leqslant r.$$

Since $\operatorname{conv} T(C)$ is dense in $C$, it follows that $\lVert T(x)-y\rVert \leqslant r$ for all $y\in C$, whence $T(x)\in C_r$.

But that contradicts the minimality of $C$ among the closed convex $T$-invariant subsets. Hence $C$ is diametral if it contains more than one point.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I remember that If $X$ be a reflective Banach space then we have $K$ be a weakly compact. I thought about my problem and I try to use: 1/ **Theorem**: Suppose $K$ is a nonempty, weakly compact, convex subset of a Banach space. Then for any mapping $$T: K \to K$$ there exists a closed convex subset of $K$ which is minimal $T$ - invariant. 2/ **Lemma**: If $K$ is a noempty, closed, convex and minimal $T$ - invariant set, then  $$K=\overline{\text{conv}}T(K)$$ Do you think so? **Daniel Fischer**

Comment: "*I haven't yet figured out how the latter implies that $C$ is a diameter set*". I think that It means we need $K$ has *normal structure*??

Comment: I'm trying to show that "If $C \ne \left \{ \text{one point} \right \}$ implies that $C$ is a diameter set." But I still have no solution!!! :(

Comment: @ **Daniel Fischer**: I think that we need to show that: $\text{diam}C=r(C)$. It means $$Z(C)=C$$ We have $C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$. And $r(C,Tx) \le r(C) \implies Tx \in Z(C), \forall x \in Z(C)$???

Comment: I don't know what $r(C)$ and $Z(C)$ denote here. What we need to show is that if $C$ consists of more than one point we have $$\sup \{ \lVert x-y\rVert : y \in C\} = \operatorname{diam}(C)$$ for all $x\in C$. Unfortunately, I had no inspiration for that so far.

Comment: $r(C)$: the Chebyshev radius of $C$. $Z(C)$: the Chebyshev center of $C$. Anyway, I found it, maybe! Can you help me? (page 3) https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F228695911_More_on_minimal_invariant_sets_for_nonexpansive_mappings%2Ffile%2F60b7d5189343576dc6.pdf&ei=2rv8Usr6E8eWiAfZrYCoAQ&usg=AFQjCNHAWROuswgrw70NoX7-YmKTz5DXmA&sig2=-9lDit07ZNhC4uNVBe5hAQ

Comment: Yes, property $\mathbf{II}$ on page $3$ is exactly what we need. It remains to fill in the details in the proof sketch there. For somebody who isn't as familiar with the topic as the authors, that looks not trivial, but it should be doable (although I cannot yet "easily observe that $K_r$ is also $T$-invariant", that needs some further thinking).

Comment: @kimtahe6 After some thinking, it really isn't difficult, proof added.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much **Daniel Fischer**.

Comment: And I'll post my solution here! I hope that my solution is correct.

Comment: The first, we have $$C=\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)$$. Next, we take $x \in Z(C) \implies r_x(C)=r(C)$. For all $y \in C$, since $T$ is nonexpansive, we have: $$||Ty-Tx|| \le ||y-x|| \le r(C)$$ Hence $T(C) \subset \bar{B}(Tx,r(C))$. Therefore, $$\overline{\text{conv}}T(C)=C \subset  \bar{B}(Tx,r(C))$$; $\implies r_{Tx}(C) \le r(C) \implies Tx \in Z(C)$. Hence, $Z(C)$ is convex, weakly compact of $C$. Moreover, $C$ is minimal. Therefore, $Z(C)=C$. Is it correct? :( **Daniel Fischer**!

Comment: I suppose you have a general theorem that $Z(C)$ is convex and closed? (If not, it's not difficult to prove.) Then all you need to show is what you did show, $T(Z(C)) \subset Z(C)$. Yes, correct, very good.